# Can't install Matplotlib in python 3.7

Tags: python, matplotlib, analysis

For install matplotlib in windows 10 64 bit machine get error showing

```
python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Animus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-urqbuxb_\unroll\
```

please help

Comment: Same happening here. I have python 3.7 64 bit version on my Windows 10 64-bit machine. I installed numpy,pandas,scipy with no problem but matplotlib is giving error and not installing.

Comment: I checked here https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files. It looks like they do not yet have a Windows version of the matplotlib wheel for Python 3.7.

Comment: I checked pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files again. On July 9th they posted wheels for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forst of all make sure you have `pip` working. To install `pip` please follow the link [Pip install](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation#pip-install) and then update the setup 
And try:

```
python -mpip install -U pip
python -mpip install -U matplotlib
```

and if does not work then use following

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: i did all those things

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Newly installed windows, only python 3.7.0 installed. No security software installed.
Those upgrade command do not work at all.
After rollback to 3.6.5, they could be installed normally.