# Pip cannot install matplotlib in Python 3.10 (other solutions do not work)

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, pip

I'm setting up a new machine, and I cannot install matplotlib. Some details:

1. I've been running `pip install matplotlib` in command prompt (I've also tried running as administrator... no luck.)
2. I've been able to install NumPy, SymPy, SciPy, and Engineering_Notation just fine.
3. I'm running Python 3.10.0 on Windows 11.
4. The error code I'm getting is: "Command errored out with exit status 1:" followed by a massive block of red text.

I've already tried the solutions mentioned in here: [Can't install Matplotlib in python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831890/cant-install-matplotlib-in-python-3-7) and here: ["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1). I've tried to find a solution from pre-existing threads, but none of them have worked for me, and I'm growing pretty desperate.

What can I do to install matplotlib?

The massive block of red text:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\jlin5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\jlin5\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mxcd8k3g\\matplotlib_174cbf1d797f449fa7213c913b6eb2a1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\jlin5\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mxcd8k3g\\matplotlib_174cbf1d797f449fa7213c913b6eb2a1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jlin5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9pu5dl4h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\jlin5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\matplotlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\jlin5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mxcd8k3g\matplotlib_174cbf1d797f449fa7213c913b6eb2a1\
    Complete output (556 lines):

    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.4.3]
          python: yes [3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC
                      v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
```

This is not in its entirety, but I can't post the full message due to Stack Overflow's character limit.

Comment: I guess we need some hints from that massive block of red text?

Comment: Okay, I will edit so that it's included.

Comment: This does, thank you. I had not realized that Python 3.10 was not yet supported.